# SwiftUI Elements in Nav Bar Don't Respond to State

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

My goal is to show a button in the navigation bar of a SwiftUI iOS app when the keyboard is visible, and hide it when the keyboard is not. I can get it to work with a button inside the main body of my view, but anything in the nav bar doesn't respond to my `@State` variable.

Here's a sample project:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showDone = false
  @State var text = "Testing"
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
      NavigationView {
          
        VStack{
          ZStack{}
          .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
              Text("Nav Bar")
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
              Button(action: {
                hideKeyboard()
              }){
                Text("Hide A")
              }
              .opacity(showDone ? 1 : 0) //<-- This doesn't work
            }
          }

          //This is just for showing the keyboard when focused
          TextField("", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

          //This button works correctly
          Button(action: {
            hideKeyboard()
          }){
            Text("Hide B")
          }
          .opacity(showDone ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)) { _ in
          print("keyboard showing")
          showDone = true
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
          print("keyboard hidden")
          showDone = false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a global function that hides the keyboard:

```
//Global function for hiding the keyboard
extension View {
  func hideKeyboard() {
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
  }
}
```

I've tried putting the `opacity` modifier on the `Text("Hide A")`, on the `Button` and on the `ToolbarItem` itself and none of them work (and putting it on the `ToolbarItem` is not allowed by the compiler).

Has anyone ever encountered navigation bar stuff not responding to `@State` variables?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was so focused on getting a modifier to work that I didn't think of another obvious option. This works fine:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
  if showDone{
    Button(action: {
      hideKeyboard()
    }){
      Text("Hide A")
    }
  }
}
```